# How I can get the one table value row by row and then show these values in another table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying  this code to fetch row by row value and perform calculation on those value but we get the result in last row that and show last row result in every row of table 2.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {

    var idx = $(this).closest('tr').index();

    $("#tbUser").find("tr").eq(idx).remove();
    $("#tbUsers").find("tr").eq(idx - 1).remove();
  });



  $("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnAdd', function() {

    $("#tbUser").append("<tr class='item'><td>Pad</td><td id='selection'>0.000307</td><td><input type='text' name='BottomHoleRate' id='BottomHoleRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='CleanVolume' id='CleanVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='BottomHoleConcentration' id='BottomHoleConcentration'></td><td>v 2.2</td><td><input type='text' name='Chemvol' id='Chemvol'></td><td><button class='btnAdd'>Add</button></td><td><button class='btnDelete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
    $("#tbUsers").append("<tr><td><input type='text' name='StageTime' id='StageTime' value=''></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryRate' id='SlurryRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='CleanRate' id='CleanRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='BlenderConcentration' id='BlenderConcentration'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantVolumeRate' id='ProppantVolumeRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantMassRate' id='ProppantMassRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantAVG' id='ProppantAVG'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantStageMass' id='ProppantStageMass'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantCumulativeMass' id='ProppantCumulativeMass'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantVolume' id='ProppantVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantCumulativeVolume' id='ProppantCumulativeVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryStageVolume' id='SlurryStageVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryCumulativeVolume' id='SlurryCumulativeVolume'></td></tr>");

    $("#tbUsers2").append("<tr><td>Pad</td></tr>");
    $("#tbUsers3").append("<tr><td>Pad</td></tr>");

  });
});


$('button').on('click', function() {

  $("#tbUser tr.item").each(function() {
    var BottomHoleRate = $(this).find("input[name='BottomHoleRate']").val(),
      CleanVolume = $(this).find("input[name = 'CleanVolume']").val();
    bhc = $(this).find("input[name = 'BottomHoleConcentration']").val();
    Chemvol = $(this).find("input[name = 'Chemvol']").val();
    // SlurryStageVolume=document.getElementById('SlurryStageVolume').value;

    SlurryRate = BottomHoleRate;
    blenderconcentration = bhc;
    ProppantAVG = document.getElementById('selection').innerText;

    proppant_stage_mass = CleanVolume * bhc;
    pro_cum_mass = proppant_stage_mass;
    proppant_vol = proppant_stage_mass * ProppantAVG;
    pro_cum_vol = proppant_vol;
    slurry_stage_vol = CleanVolume * (1 + ProppantAVG * bhc);

    slurry_cum_vol = slurry_stage_vol;

    cleanrate = SlurryRate / (1 + ProppantAVG + bhc);
    stage = slurry_stage_vol / SlurryRate;

    proppant_vol_rate = cleanrate * bhc * ProppantAVG;
    proppant_mass_rate = cleanrate * bhc;
    chem_rate1 = Chemvol * cleanrate;
    chem_vol = Chemvol * CleanVolume;
    $('input[name="StageTime"]').val(stage);
    $('input[name="SlurryRate"]').val(SlurryRate);
    $('input[name="CleanRate"]').val(cleanrate);
    $('input[name="BlenderConcentration"]').val(blenderconcentration);
    $('input[name="ProppantVolumeRate"]').val(proppant_vol_rate);
    $('input[name="ProppantMassRate"]').val(proppant_mass_rate);
    $('input[name="ProppantAVG"]').val(ProppantAVG);
    $('input[name="ProppantStageMass"]').val(proppant_stage_mass);
    $('input[name="ProppantCumulativeMass"]').val(pro_cum_vol);
    $('input[name="ProppantVolume"]').val(proppant_vol);
    $('input[name="ProppantCumulativeVolume"]').val(pro_cum_vol);
    $('input[name="SlurryStageVolume"]').val(slurry_stage_vol);
    $('input[name="SlurryCumulativeVolume"]').last().val(slurry_cum_vol);

   
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="tbUser" class="tblUser" name="tblUser">
    <tr>
      <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
      <td><button class="btnAdd">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Stage Name</th>
      <th>Proppant Selection</th>
      <th>Bottom Hole Rate</th>
      <th>Clean Volume</th>
      <th>Bottom Hole Concentration</th>
      <th>Quality</th>
      <th>Chem 1 Vol/Vol</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>table 2</h2>
  <table id="tbUsers">
    <tr>
      <th>Stage Time (min)</th>
      <th>Slurry Rate</th>
      <th>Clean Rate</th>
      <th>Blender Concentration</th>
      <th>Proppant Volume Rate</th>
      <th>Proppant Mass Rate</th>
      <th>Proppant AVG</th>
      <th>Proppant Stage Mass</th>
      <th>Proppant Cumulative Mass</th>
      <th>Proppant Volume</th>
      <th>Proppant Cumulative Volume</th>
      <th>Slurry Stage Volume</th>
      <th>Slurry Cumulative Volume</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>table 3</h2>
  <table id="tbUsers2">
    <tr>
      <th>Chem rate 1</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>table 4</h2>
  <table id="tbUsers3">
    <tr>
      <th>Chem Volume 1</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
  <button>submit</button>
```

I want to show these value in another table row by row, means the first-row value show in the first row of another table and 2nd-row value show in the 2nd row of another table and so on.

[image]

Comment: you mean same table copy? if yes you can clone first table and update the second table

Comment: not a clone of table my purpose is that i get the table1 values rows by rows and perform calculation on row values and show calculated value in table2 row by row means first row calculation value show in first row,2nd calculation value in 2nd row and so on..

Comment: yes we can share the code

Comment: kindly check the code and if you have any solution about this problem then suggest me.thanks

Comment: can we generate dynamic tables or we should append old tables?